# Xslt Concatenation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi I have xslt structure shown below

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertCriticalFlags">
<xsl:param name="src1"/>
<xsl:param name="src2"/>
<xsl:param name="src3"/>
<xsl:param name="src4"/>
<xsl:param name="src5"/>
<xsl:variable name="rslt" select="''"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$src1 = 'YES'" >
    <xsl:copy-of select="concat($rslt,',', '2TO4UNITS')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="''"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$src2 = 'YES'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="concat($rslt,',', 'COMMERCIAL')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="''"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$src3 = 'YES'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="concat($rslt,',', 'ACREAGE')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="''"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$src4 = 'YES'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="concat($rslt,',', 'MOBILEHOME')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="''"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$src5 = 'YES'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="concat($rslt,',', 'VACANTLAND')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="''"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="starts-with($rslt,',') = true">
    <xsl:copy-of select="substring($rslt,2)"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$rslt"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I would like to concatenate all the data into one variable `$rslt` but i am unable to do so
Can any one suggest how to concatenate.

Comment: Honestly speaking I didnt see Michael Kay solution. Christopher Creutzig solution also worked well.

Comment: Michael Kay's solution uses XPath 2.0 features (sequences) and functions (string-join()) to express in a single select attribute everything that's needed -- including the proper placement of the comma delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="rslt" select="string-join((
  '2TO4UNITS'[$src1 = 'YES'],
  'COMMERCIAL'[$src2 = 'YES'],
  'ACREAGE'[$src3 = 'YES'],
  'MOBILEHOME'[$src4 = 'YES'],
  'VACANTLAND'[$src5 = 'YES']), ',')"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertCriticalFlags">
<xsl:param name="src1"/>
<xsl:param name="src2"/>
<xsl:param name="src3"/>
<xsl:param name="src4"/>
<xsl:param name="src5"/>
<xsl:variable name="rslt">
  <xsl:if test="$src1 = 'YES'">,2TO4UNITS</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$src2 = 'YES'">,COMMERCIAL</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$src3 = 'YES'">,ACREAGE</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$src4 = 'YES'">,MOBILEHOME</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$src5 = 'YES'">,VACANTLAND</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="starts-with($rslt,',')">
    <xsl:copy-of select="substring($rslt,2)"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$rslt"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture a sequence of nodes into a variable in XSLT 2.0, use this form...

```
<xsl:variable name="rslt">
 ... sequence constructors go here..
<xsl:variable>
```

... instead of the form ...

```
<xsl:variable name="rslt" select="bla bla bla" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Define the all your choose condition in side one variable , that holds all the results.